# Mipmap and aliasing with Custom SCNProgram Texture

Tags: opengl, scenekit

Setting up mipmapping and aliasing/filtering with normal SCNMaterials is pretty straightforward. In my case, I need to do materials with text and intricate line patterns, and mipmapping is really necessary in these cases.

[image: Mipmap effects]

However, I need to do this with an existing custom OpenGL texture that is applied using a SCNMaterial like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641434/using-existing-opengl-texture-with-scenekit). SCNPrograms override normal SceneKit rendering and setting the mipmaps like above has zero effect.

How can I go about to achieve the same mipmap effect on a custom OpenGL texture in SceneKit?

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, but may help... `SCNMaterialProperty` contents can now be set to a `GLKTextureInfo`, so you may not need that custom shader.

Comment: That's good to know, unfortunately I am using a `GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB` that is created using a `CGLTexImageIOSurface2D` call and that does not seem possible to load into a GLKTextureInfo